# How do I properly collect user options to form a unix timestamp?

Tags: node.js, date, discord.js, unix-timestamp

I have been attempting to format this code correctly in order to display an accurate UNIX time stamp.

The Code:

```
  } else if (interaction.commandName === 'updateraidtime') {
    const month = interaction.options.getString('month');
    const day = interaction.options.getString('day');
    const year = interaction.options.getString('year');
    const time = interaction.options.getString('time');
    const timezone = interaction.options.getString('timezone');
    const raid = interaction.options.getString('raid');
    const channel = interaction.options.getChannel('channel');

    console.log(`month: ${month}`);
    console.log(`day: ${day}`);
    console.log(`year: ${year}`);
    console.log(`time: ${time}`);
    console.log(`timezone: ${timezone}`);
    console.log(`raidName: ${raid}`);
    console.log(`channel: ${channel}`);

    // Format time string
    const formattedTime = time + " " + timezone;

    // Calculate Unix timestamp from inputs
    const dateString = `${month} ${day}, ${year} ${formattedTime}`;
    const date = new Date(dateString);
    const timestamp = date.getTime() / 1000;

    console.log(`dateString: ${dateString}`);
    console.log(`timestamp: ${timestamp}`);

    // Update channel topic
    await channel.setTopic(`Upcoming raid: ${raid} | Time: ${timestamp}`);
    await interaction.reply(`Raid time updated for channel ${channel.name}!`);
```

This and other variations that I have tried output the following logs from my testing:

```
month: March
day: 5
year: 2023
time: 15:00
timezone: US/Hawaii
raidName: TATERS
channel: <#815347255531143219>
dateString: March 5 2023 15:00 US/Hawaii
timestamp: NaN
```

I do not undertand why the timestamp is NaN. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried other methods of manipulating the date constructor but none have worked.

Comment: `March 5 2023 15:00 US/Hawaii` is not a correct format for Date constructor, specifically `US/Hawaii` breaks it, you can read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)